# Django Bootstrap 4 unable to use scss

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I'm trying to set a 4-column card view with this: [Card Columns](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/card/#card-columns)

Here is a successful online example: [DEMO](http://www.codeply.com/go/nHZg5n2vuE)

I followed [this](https://django-compressor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart/) tutorial to setup Django compressor.

I have following code in `main.scss` file:

```
@import 'bootstrap';
.card-columns {
  @include media-breakpoint-only(lg) {
    column-count: 4;
  }
  @include media-breakpoint-only(xl) {
    column-count: 5;
  }
}
```

And I can't import Bootstrap. I tried to put the `bootstrap.css` in the same folder but the system pops the error says:

> Error: no mixin named media-breakpoint-only

I'm kind of new to this. How do I fix it? Thanks.

Comment: Have you read [this](http://django-compressor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage/#css-notes)?

Comment: Or [this](http://django-compressor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/settings/#django.conf.settings.COMPRESS_PRECOMPILERS)?

Comment: did the answer below solved your question?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should put this into your `settings.py` file:

```
COMPRESS_PRECOMPILERS = (
    ('text/x-sass', 'sass main.scss output_file.css')
)
```

in order for the compressor to "precompile" your `.scss` file.